# How to stop encoding strings in ASP.NET MVC 3 beta 1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.0

How to stop encoding strings in ASP.NET MVC 3 beta 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean HTML encoding?

in the comments of this post, it says you can use the helper method Html.Raw

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx

example from that post (Razor views, guessing same for other view engines?)

```
@{
    string content = "<b>Hello World</b>";
}

This is some html: @Html.Raw(content)
```

another good post about Raw method

http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2010/12/27/HtmlRawRazorViewEngine.aspx

Comment: Thanks house9 but where Raw() is located? I can't find that! System.Web.WebPages.Html?

Comment: I believe it is under System.Web.Mvc.Html - not 100% sure though

Comment: Thanks again but still i can't figure it out! Are you have use this before?

Comment: also you said you are using MVC 3 beta 1 - you should probably get the latest release - http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3 (MVC 3 Release Candidate 2)

Comment: No, I have found Raw() in System.Web.WebPages.HtmlHelper class, but that is **internal**.

Comment: I upgraded to MVC RC2 but still there is no Raw() in Html property of View. Have you tested this?

Comment: I have not tested this; not on a PC until monday

Comment: Oppps! I have installed RC1! thanks @house9 my problem solved ;)